# Append a string to end of line between quotation marks

Tags: ansible

I have text file as following

```
JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS="-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/jira/"
```

I need to add `-Djira.startup.warnings.disable=true` argument to the end of line and between que double quotes (`""`) so it will look like

```
JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS="-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/jira/ -Djira.startup.warnings.disable=true"
```

I tried to use

```yaml
- name: append TTLAfterFinished to existing list of feature-gates
  lineinfile:
    path: "setenv.sh"
    backrefs: yes
    regexp: "^(.*JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=.*)$"
    line: '\1 -Djira.startup.warnings.disable=true"'
```

It append the argument to the end of the line, but keep the original `"`

```
JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS="-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/jira/" -Djira.startup.warnings.disable=true"
```

How should I make this replacement work properly?
In addition, in the end of the playbook I will need to clean this argument out of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way would be to match only the Java machine arguments inside the variable with a regex like:

```regex
^.*JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS="(.*)".*$
```

Then rewrite the variable name in the `line` parameter, so your task would look like:

```yaml
- lineinfile:
    path: "setenv.sh"
    backrefs: yes
    regexp: '^.*JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS="(.*)".*$'
    line: 'JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS="\1 -Djira.startup.warnings.disable=true"'
```

There is also the complicated way to have three groups to match the different parts:

1. the beginning of the line with the variable name: `^(.*JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=")`
2. everything between the quotes `(.*)`
3. the closing quote and the possible trailing spaces until the end of the line `(".*)$`

In this scenario, your task will look like:

```yaml
- lineinfile:
    path: "setenv.sh"
    backrefs: yes
    regexp: '^(.*JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=")(.*)(".*)$'
    line: '\1\2 -Djira.startup.warnings.disable=true\3'
```

---

Then to remove it, as long as you are sure it is the last argument before the closing quotes, you can do something as simple as having the regex match it, but not in the group, so when you use the back reference, it will just be remove:

```yaml
- lineinfile:
    path: "setenv.sh"
    backrefs: yes
    regexp: '^.*JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS="(.*) -Djira.startup.warnings.disable=true".*$'
    line: 'JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS="\1"'
```

Comment: thank you for explanation and it resolved my issue